# setcookie Security Error in Microsoft Edge

Tags: php

When I use setcookie,security error is showing in Microsoft Edge.
'A 'set-cookie' header doesn't have the 'secure' directive.'
My connection is insecure http connection.
How to prevent it ?

I used php setcookie function with various patterns.

Comment: Try `CookieManager - Cookie Editor` to see properties of sent cookie. It helped me to figure out that I still use http cookie on my https website. I think in your case the problem will be with http connection. Use https connection (move the site on live dev server) or do not use 'https' (secured) cookie during  the development.

Comment: *I used php setcookie function with various patterns.* - can you edit your question, and post the code which sets the cookie?